# I want to use stickyfloat.js with bootstrap navbar fixed

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use stickyfloat as side menu and want to display content in the same page, with bootstrap navbar fixed top.

So that when menu from stickyfloat is clicked i want the content to offset some 100px from top. So that it wont gets hidden.

This is the link where i am stuck on "http://www.station525salon.com/services"

Please do help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Logic :-

On `click` of any menu item in your sticky menu, give your main `container` class a `margin-top: 100px; // as u need`.

And remember to remove this 'margin-top: 0' when the user scrolls on top of the page.

Comment: Thank you Anup, i tried that too. It works in my local but not online.I have updated the link  "http://www.station525salon.com/services"
any help???

Thanks